# Reading multiple excel files using a loop and append

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple excel files. Each time one excel file is read I would like to append it to the other excel file. At the end, I should end up with one dataframe which has the content of all excel files.

How can I do that in a for loop?

Here is my attempt:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    temp = pd.read_excel(path[i])
    temp_final=temp
```

The idea here is to have temp_final containing the content of all excel files. Something similar to `temp_final=[excelfile1, excelfile2]` `pd.concat(temp_final)`

I would welcome any idea on how I can finish this `for` loop. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is **not** to continually append to an existing dataframe.

It is much more efficient to read your dataframes into a list, then concatenate them in one call:

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(path[i]) for i in range(1, 10)]

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Alternative syntax:

```
dfs = list(map(pd.read_excel, path[:10]))
```

Comment: Thank you JPP. this is much better that my proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this answer.

```
temp=pd.read_excel(path[0])

for i in range(1,2):
    print(i)
    temp1 = pd.read_excel(path[i])
    temp=temp.append(temp1)
```

does it make sense to do for loop that way?

Answer (score 0):

i ve got around 1000 excel files located in one folder:

C:/BD/KEN

all the files had the naming format:

'Ken <#> dated .xlsx'

i needed to read all the files, table from the first sheet and then merge all into one dataframe for further manipulation and having ONE BIG excel file to work with:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#list of <#> series of excel files (around 1000 files total)
names = ['1125','1126','1127']

#column names
ColNames = ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h'] 

#empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=ColNames)

for x,y,z in os.walk('C:/BD/KEN'):
    for i in z:
        if i.split()[1] in names:
            print(i)
            try:
                temp = pd.read_excel('C:/BD/KEN'+i)
            except:
                print('ALERT')
            df.append([temp])

df.to_excel('C:/BD/TOTAL.xlsx', index=None)
print('DONE")
```

os.walk produces tuples (folder path, folder name, file name)

so 'z' is the file name as str